# Authorization code has different structure than example code

Tags: sonos

So I'm trying to build a application following [the Sonos documentation](https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/authorize/), which can control my Sonos speaker.
Sending a GET request to get a authorization code works just fine, with the exception that my code looks like this **"qNvyst9Y"** while the [example response](https://developer.sonos.com/reference/authorization-api/create-authorization-code/) shows following code **"f10072fa6-2134-4fe1-93fd-ca5b9cffa738"**. So the format of my code is not the same as the example code's format.

Am I missing something or why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that the Authorization Code you received is valid. We recently changed the format, so will update the documentation to reflect this change.

Thank you for calling this out!