# Sonos API sends too short auth code in return?

Tags: api, oauth-2.0, sonos

Turning to all you smart people out there for help, tips and trix :)

I want to connect my NodeRed instance to the Sonos API to control my speakers in various ways. During the OAUTH process however, after logging in with my username and password for my account, the auth code being sent back to me through my redirect_uri seems to be too short? In the developers' guide the example auth code looks like this:
f10072fa6-2134-4fe1-93fd-ca5b9cffa738
where in my case, I just receive the first part up until the first dash sign. Eg.:f10072fa6

At first I ran the connection through a NetScaler, then I changed to using a Nginx Reverse Proxy thinking that the Netscaler might have truncated the URL (for some very odd reason), but the result turned out the same..

Ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Authorization code you received is correct. The Authorization code format was recently changed and the documentation needs to be updated to reflect this. This question was also answered in [Authorization code has different structure than example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63014590/authorization-code-has-different-structure-than-example-code).

Thanks!
-Mark

Comment: Hej, and thanks a bunch Mark! I did search before I posted, but obviously not well enough. I'm having difficulties in the next step, aquiring the token – but then at least I know that the auth code is correct and I can focus my troubleshooting elsewhere! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [nodered-sonos](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-sonos-plus) to control your speakers. No need to setup oauth2 and using the cloud based api, if you can also have super fast local control of your speakers.

I'm using a combination of the following tools for total control of the speakers:

- MQTT server of your choice **in Docker** (I'm using emqx)
- [Sonos2mqtt](https://svrooij.io/sonos2mqtt/), my own app to connect sonos to mqtt **in docker**
- Node red with normal mqtt in/out flows.

My Favorite flows:

- Join playbar to group if group starts playing
- Pause group is playbar leaves group (it leaves if I turn on the TV, that should stop the music)
- Play ring sound (on all speakers) if someone presses the doorbell
- Announce (text-to-speech) when the backdoor is opened